# Define KSQL STRUCT on JSON valued topic with different types

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

(**Edit**: slight edits to better reflect intention, but large edit due to progress made.)

A topic `"t_raw"` is given messages of multiple types, where they all contain a common `"type"` key:

```
{"type":"key1","data":{"ts":"2018-11-20 19:20:21.1","a":1,"b":"hello"}}
{"type":"key2","data":{"ts":"2018-11-20 19:20:22.2","a":1,"c":11,"d":"goodbye"}}
{"type":"key1","data":{"ts":"2018-11-20 19:20:23.3","a":2,"b":"hello2"}}
{"type":"key2","data":{"ts":"2018-11-20 19:20:24.4","a":3,"c":22,"d":"goodbye2"}}
```

Ultimately, I need to split this into other streams where they will be chopped/aggregated/processed. I'd like to be able to use `STRUCT` for everything, but my current effort has me doing this:

```
create stream raw (type varchar, data varchar) \
  with (kafka_topic='t_raw', value_format='JSON');
```

for the first level, then

```
create stream key1 with (TIMESTAMP='ts', timestamp_format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S') as \
  select \
    extractjsonfield(data, '$.ts') as ts, \
    extractjsonfield(data, '$.a') as a, extractjsonfield(data, '$.b') as b \
  from raw where type='key1';
create stream key2 with (TIMESTAMP='ts', timestamp_format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S') as \
  select \
    extractjsonfield(data, '$.ts') as ts, \
    extractjsonfield(data, '$.a') as a, extractjsonfield(data, '$.c') as c, \
    extractjsonfield(data, '$.d') as d \
  from raw where type='key2';
```

This seems to work, but with the recent addition of `STRUCT`, is there a way to use it in lieu of `extractjsonfield` as done above?

```
ksql> select * from key1;
1542741621100 | null | 2018-11-20 19:20:21.1 | 1 | hello
1542741623300 | null | 2018-11-20 19:20:23.3 | 2 | hello2
^CQuery terminated
ksql> select * from key2;
1542741622200 | null | 2018-11-20 19:20:22.2 | 1 | 11 | goodbye
1542741624400 | null | 2018-11-20 19:20:24.4 | 3 | 22 | goodbye2
```

If not with `STRUCT`, is there a straight-forward way to do this with vanilla kafka-streams (vice `ksql`, ergo the [apache-kafka-streams](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka-streams) tag)?

Is there a more kafka-esque/efficient/elegant way to parse this? 
I cannot define it as an empty `STRUCT<>`

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM some_input ( type VARCHAR, data struct<> ) \
      WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='t1', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
line 1:52: extraneous input '<>' expecting {',', ')'}
```

There is [some (not-so-recent) discussion](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/1538) on being able to do something like

```
CREATE STREAM key1 ( a INT, b VARCHAR ) AS \
  SELECT data->* from some_input where type = 'key1';
```

FYI: the above solution will not work in confluent-5.0.0, [a recent patch](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/pull/1962) fixed the `extractjsonfield` bug and enabled this solution.

The real data has several more similar message types. They all contain `"type"` and `"data"` keys (and no others at the top-level), and almost all have the `"ts"` timestamp equivalent nested within `"data"`.

Comment: I know this is possible with Avro, and making that c field in the data have some otherwise default value in the Avro schema, but not sure if JSON can work this way

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, the reason I had (and have kept) the [tag:apache-kafka-streams] is that, since this is a stream and not (yet) a table, it might be solved via a non-`ksql` mechanism. I'm open to it, even though it isn't a proficiency of mine. Thanks for the edit, though.

Comment: @cricket_007, I didn't see anything in the avro spec that allowed me to have a conditional `"data"` definition there, nor in the def within `create stream ...`, so that doesn't surprise me wholly. Thanks.

Comment: For this case, you should mention this in the question :)

Comment: Working on an edit as we type ...

Comment: If `VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO'`, then you don't need to give the fields in KSQL. They are referenced from the schema regisitry, where the Avro schema could have `"field": "c", "type": ["null", "int"], "default":"null"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this - KSQL doesn't mind if a column doesn't exist, you just get a `null` value.

### Test data setup

Populate some test data into the topic:

```
kafkacat -b kafka:29092 -t t_raw -P <<EOF
{"type":"key1","data":{"ts":"2018-11-20 19:20:21.1","a":1,"b":"hello"}}
{"type":"key2","data":{"ts":"2018-11-20 19:20:22.2","a":1,"c":11,"d":"goodbye"}}
{"type":"key1","data":{"ts":"2018-11-20 19:20:23.3","a":2,"b":"hello2"}}
{"type":"key2","data":{"ts":"2018-11-20 19:20:24.4","a":3,"c":22,"d":"goodbye2"}}
EOF
```

Dump the topic to KSQL console for inspection:

```
ksql> PRINT 't_raw' FROM BEGINNING;
Format:JSON
{"ROWTIME":1542965737436,"ROWKEY":"null","type":"key1","data":{"ts":"2018-11-20 19:20:21.1","a":1,"b":"hello"}}
{"ROWTIME":1542965737436,"ROWKEY":"null","type":"key2","data":{"ts":"2018-11-20 19:20:22.2","a":1,"c":11,"d":"goodbye"}}
{"ROWTIME":1542965737436,"ROWKEY":"null","type":"key1","data":{"ts":"2018-11-20 19:20:23.3","a":2,"b":"hello2"}}
{"ROWTIME":1542965737437,"ROWKEY":"null","type":"key2","data":{"ts":"2018-11-20 19:20:24.4","a":3,"c":22,"d":"goodbye2"}}
^CTopic printing ceased
ksql>
```

### Model the source stream of data

Create a stream over it. Note the use of `STRUCT` and reference of every possible column:

```
CREATE STREAM T (TYPE VARCHAR, \
                 DATA STRUCT< \
                      TS VARCHAR, \
                      A INT, \
                      B VARCHAR, \
                      C INT, \
                      D VARCHAR>) \
        WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='t_raw',\
              VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

Set offset to earliest so that we query the whole topic, and then use KSQL to access the full stream:

```
ksql> SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';
Successfully changed local property 'auto.offset.reset' from 'null' to 'earliest'
ksql>
ksql> SELECT * FROM T;
1542965737436 | null | key1 | {TS=2018-11-20 19:20:21.1, A=1, B=hello, C=null, D=null}
1542965737436 | null | key2 | {TS=2018-11-20 19:20:22.2, A=1, B=null, C=11, D=goodbye}
1542965737436 | null | key1 | {TS=2018-11-20 19:20:23.3, A=2, B=hello2, C=null, D=null}
1542965737437 | null | key2 | {TS=2018-11-20 19:20:24.4, A=3, B=null, C=22, D=goodbye2}
^CQuery terminated
```

Query the types individually, using the `->` operator to access the nested elements:

```
ksql> SELECT DATA->A,DATA->B FROM T WHERE TYPE='key1'  LIMIT 2;
1 | hello
2 | hello2

ksql> SELECT DATA->A,DATA->C,DATA->D FROM T WHERE TYPE='key2' LIMIT 2;
1 | 11 | goodbye
3 | 22 | goodbye2
```

### Persist the data in separate Kafka topics:

Populate target topics with the separated data:

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM TYPE_1 AS SELECT DATA->TS, DATA->A, DATA->B FROM T WHERE TYPE='key1';

Message
----------------------------
Stream created and running
----------------------------
ksql> CREATE STREAM TYPE_2 AS SELECT DATA->TS, DATA->A, DATA->C, DATA->D FROM T WHERE TYPE='key2';

Message
----------------------------
Stream created and running
----------------------------
```

Schema for the new streams:

```
ksql> DESCRIBE TYPE_1;

Name                 : TYPE_1
Field    | Type
--------------------------------------
ROWTIME  | BIGINT           (system)
ROWKEY   | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system)
DATA__TS | VARCHAR(STRING)
DATA__A  | INTEGER
DATA__B  | VARCHAR(STRING)
--------------------------------------
For runtime statistics and query details run: DESCRIBE EXTENDED <Stream,Table>;
ksql> DESCRIBE TYPE_2;

Name                 : TYPE_2
Field    | Type
--------------------------------------
ROWTIME  | BIGINT           (system)
ROWKEY   | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system)
DATA__TS | VARCHAR(STRING)
DATA__A  | INTEGER
DATA__C  | INTEGER
DATA__D  | VARCHAR(STRING)
--------------------------------------
```

Topics underpin each KSQL stream:

```
ksql> LIST TOPICS;

Kafka Topic                 | Registered | Partitions | Partition Replicas | Consumers | ConsumerGroups
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
t_raw                       | true       | 1          | 1                  | 2         | 2
TYPE_1                      | true       | 4          | 1                  | 0         | 0
TYPE_2                      | true       | 4          | 1                  | 0         | 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice walk-through. I don't know yet how best to benchmark ... do you know if there is any "significant" difference (in speed, robustness, etc) between using this union'ed `struct` versus the `extractjsonfield` method?